# TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'hidden'

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to visualize my GRU model using PyTorchViz but every time I run this code it gives me an error.

I want something like this in the

[image: picture]

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torchviz import make_dot, make_dot_from_trace

model = IC_V6(f.tokens)
x = torch.randn(1,8)

make_dot(model(x), params=dict(model.named_parameters()))
```

here is my Class for holding the data

```
class Flickr8KImageCaptionDataset:

    def __init__(self):

        all_data = json.load(open('caption_datasets/dataset_flickr8k.json', 'r'))
        all_data=all_data['images']

        self.training_data = []
        self.test_data = []
        self.w2i = {ENDWORD: 0, STARTWORD: 1}
        self.word_frequency = {ENDWORD: 0, STARTWORD: 0}
        self.i2w = {0: ENDWORD, 1: STARTWORD}
        self.tokens = 2 #END is default
        self.batch_index = 0

        for data in all_data:
            if(data['split']=='train'):
                self.training_data.append(data)
            else:
                self.test_data.append(data)

            for sentence in data['sentences']:
                for token in sentence['tokens']:
                    if(token not in self.w2i.keys()):
                        self.w2i[token] = self.tokens
                        self.i2w[self.tokens] = token
                        self.tokens +=1
                        self.word_frequency[token] = 1
                    else:
                        self.word_frequency[token] += 1

    def image_to_tensor(self,filename):
        image = Image.open(filename)
        image = TF.resize(img=image, size=(HEIGHT,WIDTH))

        image = TF.to_tensor(pic=image)
        image = TF.normalize(image, mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                     std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])

        return torch.unsqueeze(image,0)


    def return_train_batch(self): #size of 1 always

        #np.random.shuffle(self.training_data)
        for index in range(len(self.training_data)):

        #index = np.random.randint(len(self.training_data))
            sentence_index = np.random.randint(len(self.training_data[index]['sentences']))
            output_sentence_tokens = deepcopy(self.training_data[index]['sentences'][sentence_index]['tokens'])
            output_sentence_tokens.append(ENDWORD) #corresponds to end word

            image = self.image_to_tensor('/home/vincent/Documents/Final Code/Flicker8k_Dataset/'+self.training_data[index]['filename'])


            yield image, list(map(lambda x: self.w2i[x], output_sentence_tokens)), output_sentence_tokens, index

    def convert_tensor_to_word(self, output_tensor):
        output = F.log_softmax(output_tensor.detach().squeeze(), dim=0).numpy()
        return self.i2w[np.argmax(output)]

    def convert_sentence_to_tokens(self, sentence):

        tokens = sentence.split(" ")
        converted_tokens= list(map(lambda x: self.w2i[x], tokens))
        converted_tokens.append(self.w2i[ENDWORD])
        return converted_tokens

    def caption_image_greedy(self, net, image_filename, max_words=15): #non beam search, no temperature implemented
        net.eval()
        inception.eval()
        image_tensor = self.image_to_tensor(image_filename)
        hidden=None
        embedding=None
        words = []

        input_token = STARTWORD
        input_tensor = torch.tensor(self.w2i[input_token]).type(torch.LongTensor)


        for i in range(max_words):

            if(i==0):
                out, hidden=net(input_tensor, hidden=image_tensor, process_image=True)
            else:
                out, hidden=net(input_tensor, hidden)

            word = self.convert_tensor_to_word(out)

            input_token = self.w2i[word]
            input_tensor = torch.tensor(input_token).type(torch.LongTensor)


            if(word==ENDWORD):
                break
            else:
                words.append(word)

        return ' '.join(words)


    def forward_beam(self, net, hidden, process_image, partial_sentences, sentences, topn_words=5, max_sentences=10):

        max_words = 50

        hidden_index = {}

        while(sentences<max_sentences):

            #print("Sentences: ",sentences)

            new_partial_sentences = []
            new_partial_sentences_logp = []
            new_partial_avg_logp= []

            if(len(partial_sentences[-1][0])>max_words):
                break



            for partial_sentence in partial_sentences:

                input_token = partial_sentence[0][-1]

                input_tensor = torch.tensor(self.w2i[input_token]).type(torch.FloatTensor)

                if(partial_sentence[0][-1]==STARTWORD):
                    out, hidden=net(input_tensor, hidden, process_image=True)
                else:
                    out, hidden=net(input_tensor, torch.tensor(hidden_index[input_token]))

                #take first topn words and add as children to root

                out = F.log_softmax(out.detach().squeeze(), dim=0).numpy()
                out_indexes = np.argsort(out)[::-1][:topn_words]


                for out_index in out_indexes:

                    if(self.i2w[out_index]==ENDWORD):
                        sentences=sentences+1

                    else:

                        total_logp = float(out[out_index]) + partial_sentence[1]
                        new_partial_sentences_logp.append(total_logp)
                        new_partial_sentences.append([np.concatenate((partial_sentence[0], [self.i2w[out_index]])),total_logp])

                        len_words = len(new_partial_sentences[-1][0])



                        new_partial_avg_logp.append(total_logp/len_words)

                        #print(self.i2w[out_index])

                        hidden_index[self.i2w[out_index]] = deepcopy(hidden.detach().numpy())




            #select topn partial sentences

            top_indexes = np.argsort(new_partial_sentences_logp)[::-1][:topn_words]


            new_partial_sentences = np.array(new_partial_sentences)[top_indexes]

            #print("New partial sentences (topn):", new_partial_sentences)

            partial_sentences = new_partial_sentences


        return partial_sentences

    def caption_image_beam_search(self, net, image_filename, topn_words=10, max_sentences=10):

        net.eval()
        inception.eval()
        image_tensor = self.image_to_tensor(image_filename)
        hidden=None
        embedding=None
        words = []


        sentences = 0
        partial_sentences = [[[STARTWORD], 0.0]]
        #root_id = hash(input_token) #for start word
        #nodes = {}

        #nodes[root_id] = Node(root_id, [STARTWORD, 0], None)

        partial_sentences = self.forward_beam(net, image_tensor, True, partial_sentences, sentences,  topn_words, max_sentences)

        logp = []

        joined_sentences = []

        for partial_sentence in partial_sentences:


            joined_sentences.append([' '.join(partial_sentence[0][1:]),partial_sentence[1]])



        return joined_sentences

    def print_beam_caption(self, net, train_filename,num_captions=0):
        beam_sentences = f.caption_image_beam_search(net,train_filename)
        if(num_captions==0):
            num_captions=len(beam_sentences)
        for sentence in beam_sentences[:num_captions]:
            print(sentence[0]+" [",sentence[1], "]")
```

and here is my GRU model

```
class IC_V6(nn.Module):

    #V2: Fed image vector directly as hidden and fed words generated as iputs back to LSTM
    #V3: Added an embedding layer between words input and GRU/LSTM

    def __init__(self, token_dict_size):
        super(IC_V6, self).__init__()

        #Input is an image of height 500, and width 500


        self.embedding_size = INPUT_EMBEDDING
        self.hidden_state_size = HIDDEN_SIZE
        self.token_dict_size = token_dict_size
        self.output_size = OUTPUT_EMBEDDING

        self.batchnorm = nn.BatchNorm1d(self.embedding_size)

        self.input_embedding = nn.Embedding(self.token_dict_size, self.embedding_size)

        self.embedding_dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.22)
        self.gru_layers = 3

        self.gru = nn.GRU(input_size=self.embedding_size, hidden_size=self.hidden_state_size, num_layers=self.gru_layers, dropout=0.22)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(self.hidden_state_size, self.output_size)
        self.out = nn.Linear(self.output_size, token_dict_size)

    def forward(self, input_tokens, hidden, process_image=False, use_inception=True):



        if(USE_GPU):
            device = torch.device('cuda')
        else:
            device = torch.device('cpu')

        if(process_image):
            if(use_inception):
                inp=self.embedding_dropout(inception(hidden))
            else:
                inp=hidden
            #inp=self.batchnorm(inp)
            hidden=torch.zeros((self.gru_layers,1, self.hidden_state_size))
        else:
            inp=self.embedding_dropout(self.input_embedding(input_tokens.view(1).type(torch.LongTensor).to(device)))
            #inp=self.batchnorm(inp)


        hidden = hidden.view(self.gru_layers,1,-1)
        inp = inp.view(1,1,-1)

        out, hidden = self.gru(inp, hidden)
        out = self.out(self.linear(out))



        return out, hidden
```

this is how I called them:

```
f = Flickr8KImageCaptionDataset()
net = IC_V6(f.tokens)
```

the error is:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-7993fc1a032f> in <module>
      6 x = torch.randn(1,8)
      7 
----> 8 make_dot(model(x), params=dict(model.named_parameters()))

~/anaconda3/envs/Thesis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    487             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    488         else:
--> 489             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    490         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    491             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)
```

> TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'hidden'

What should I do to solve this problem? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: How is `forward()` being called?  I don't see any calls to it here.  Please post the entire error message.

Comment: @JohnGordon I've updated the code. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I think the error message is pretty straight forward. You have two positional arguments `input_tokens` and `hidden` for your `forward()`.

Python complains that one of them (`hidden`)  is missing when you call your `forward()` function.

Looking at your code, you call your `forward` like this:

```
model(x)
```

So `x` is mapped to `input_tokens`, but you need to hand over a second argument `hidden`.

So you need to call it like this, providing your hidden state:

```
model(x, hidden)
```

Comment: What should I do input to that code? I tried to do this but it gives http://dpaste.com/3B4401W me error.

Comment: @Vincent You can initialize your hidden state with a tensor like this: `torch.zeros(num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size) `, where the variables are matching your desired specifications. However this is not really related to your original question. I suggest that you create a new question if you encounter new errors. Further it might be beneficial to learn a bit more about PyTorch and how RNNs work in general!